# Javascript setInterval working on localhost but does't work on live

Tags: javascript

Javascript setInterval working on localhost but does't work not repeat on live on my free webhost, http://myownprojects.co.nf/,  when i change browser tab and come back again my page then all comments are visible, Actually I am working on comments box I want to repeat all comments every 1 second so that another new comment join with all comments plz solve my problem??

Here is my code

```
function timer(){

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        all_com = new XMLHttpRequest;
    }
    all_com.onreadystatechange=
    function()
    {
        if(all_com.readyState==4 && all_com.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("comments").innerHTML=all_com.responseText; 
        }
    }
    all_com.open("GET","all_comments.php");
    all_com.send();
}
setInterval("timer()",1000);
```

Comment: `setInterval(timer,1000);` or `setInterval(function(){ timer() },1000);`

Comment: Also make sure to put the definition of ``all_com.onreadystatechange`` inside the ``if`` condition to avoid problems.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how it is even running in `localhost` as it is noway dependent on `host` or `url`

Your mistake is this part

```
setInterval("timer()",1000);
```

This is not the correct syntax. In timing event the first expected argument is a function followed by the time in millisecond

But you are passing a string "timer()" which is wrong. So you have use it

```
setInterval(timer,1000);
```

or

```
setInterval(function(){
   timer();
  },1000)
```

Comment: Not strictly true. The first argument to setInterval/setTimeout can be a string, which is then eval'd.

I mean - never ever do this. But syntactically its correct.

There really isn't enough information in the original question. Javascript is in no way reliant on web host/localhost etc. its just run in the browser. A codepen/plunkr or link to where it is not working would be useful.